# Counting file from a date range depending on date modified

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file path in Column A and want to display the count of how many files are between a date range, and if there are any files I want to be able to have a comment on the cell showing the file names and dates.

I have a code that I've gotten help on, but when the code runs it counts all the files in the folder and the comment only appears on the last number in the column.

```
Sub CreateMouseoverList(Optional FileFilter As String, Optional LowDate As Date, Optional HighDate As Date)

    Dim Cell    As Range
    Dim Ext     As Variant
    Dim File    As Object
    Dim FileCnt As Long
    Dim Files   As Object
    Dim Folder  As Variant
    Dim Item    As Variant
    Dim List()  As Variant
    Dim MaxLen  As Long
    Dim ModDate As Date
    Dim m       As Long
    Dim n       As Long
    Dim Note    As Comment
    Dim Text    As String

        If IsMissing(FileFilter) Then FileFilter = "*.*"

        ' // Is there is no LowDate then use 1.
        If LowDate = 0 Then LowDate = 2

        ' // If there is no HighDate then use today's date.
        If HighDate = 0 Then HighDate = Now()

        With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            For Each Cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
                FileCnt = 0
                ReDim List(1 To 1)

                Set Note = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Comment
                If Note Is Nothing Then Set Note = Cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment

                Note.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, Len(Note.Text)).Delete
                Note.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.FontStyle = "regular"

                Set Folder = .Namespace(Cell.Value)

                If Not Folder Is Nothing Then
                    Set Files = Folder.Items

                    For Each Ext In Split(FileFilter, ";")
                        Files.Filter 64, Ext

                        Text = vbLf & " " & Ext & " Files | " & vbLf

                        List(UBound(List)) = Text
                        n = UBound(List) + 1
                        ReDim Preserve List(1 To n)

                        Text = String(Len(Text), "-") & " | " & vbLf

                        List(UBound(List)) = Text
                        n = UBound(List) + 1
                        ReDim Preserve List(1 To n)

                        Note.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "Courier New"
                        Note.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

                        For Each File In Files
                            ModDate = File.ModifyDate
                            If ModDate >= LowDate And HighDate <= HighDate Then
                                FileCnt = FileCnt + 1
                                Text = File.Name & " | " & ModDate & vbLf
                                List(n) = Text
                                n = UBound(List) + 1
                                ReDim Preserve List(1 To n)
                                If Len(Text) > MaxLen Then MaxLen = Len(Text)
                            End If
                        Next File
                    Next Ext

                    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileCnt
                Else
                    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Folder not found."
                End If
            Next Cell
        End With

        For Each Item In List
            m = Len(Item)
            n = Note.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.count + 1
            Item = Split(Item, "|")
            If UBound(Item) > -1 Then
                Text = Item(0) & String(MaxLen - m, 32) & Item(1)
                Note.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(n, Len(Text)).Insert Text
            End If
        Next Item

End Sub

Sub TestIt()
    Call CreateMouseoverList("*.txt;*.xls", "4/1/2019","6/10/2019")
End Sub
```

I would like to be able to count all the files that are between a date range and display what the files are as well as the count.

Comment: That last `For Each` block should be inside your main loop, maybe right before `Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileCnt`

Comment: That did add all the comments to the list, Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to count the files that are between a certain date range and display those.

Comment: `If ModDate >= LowDate And HighDate <= HighDate Then`  - seems to be a problem with that second comparision: you're comparing `HighDate` with itself

Comment: So what should I put if I'm looking for files between 4/1/2019 and 6/10/2019?

Comment: `If ModDate >= LowDate And ModDate  <= HighDate Then`

Comment: That makes sense to put it that way. I'm trying to test grabbing files from 6/1/2019 - 6/10/2019, but it still seems to be pulling all files. Is there something certain I should be putting for my LowDate and HighDate?

Comment: Works for me with that change.

Comment: Hmm I keep getting Invalid Procedure call or argument. I'll keep messing with it. Might have typed something in without realizing it. Thank you for your help

Comment: I got it, Thank you. I must have had something changed. I just pasted my post and made the changes you helped me with. Thank you so much!

Comment: I figured out my error. When I want to see if there are any files from 1/1/2019 - 2/1/2019, but there isn't it comes back with that error. Is there a way to make it just say 0 if there is no files?

Comment: Where exactly does it error?

Comment: The error appears if there are no files to be found. It doesn't highlight any code. Just displays the error Invalid Procedure call or argument, then closes the VBA

Comment: There's no "debug" button?

Comment: No, I'm trying to find files that are older that shouldn't be there. So when I put a date range that should bring back some 0'

Comment: 0's or some numbers the same error pops up with either OK or Help

Comment: `String(MaxLen - m, 32)` - MaxLen is 0 when there are no files found